# Highlight a subview in iOS when selecting a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, storyboard

The issue I'm referring to is present in this sample app: https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/iOS

How can I make sure that the subview with the icons also gets highlighted when I select the table cell? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `backgroundColor = .clear` for the views that should highlight. In the particular example they are the `UIImageView` and the `UICollectionView`.

Also the `UIImageView` has a `highlightedImage` property, so it's possible to provide an alternative image which appears when the `UICollectionViewCell` is selected.

Comment: but other image views get highlighted (like the little play icon); it's only the content of the CollectionView inside the TableViewCell that doesn't

Comment: You are right. The builtin logic to highlight items works if make their background color as clear. Updated the answer.